# Create a tool to open local pdf files on android tablet

Tags: javascript, android, html, pdf

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but my knowledge is very limited on this subject. I'm not asking for a complete solution, I just need a little push in the right direction.

I have an adroid tablet with a lot of pdf files on the sdcard. Now I want to make a tool to scan a barcode with the filename and open this pdf file. The barcode will be like `test` and the corresponding file will be `file://sdcard/pdf/test.pdf`. 
The barcode scanner gives an enter after scanning so I only need a textbox on screen and the enter key to initiate the opening activity. We'd rather not connect this tablet to our network, so it doesn't have an internet connection.

I have tried to make an app for this, but since my android programming skills are pretty limited this didn't work out for me. 
Now I am trying to make a web app with either php or javascript. This isn't really working out for me since my experience with either of those is limited as well. Initially I was thinking of an MS Access tool in VBA but since there's no runtime for Android this idea doesn't work out.

I've already searched for a solution, but haven't found anything I could use.

Does anyone have a suggestion on with kind of tool I should use? And perhaps put me in the right direction. For more information, please ask.

**UPDATE 1:**

Right now I've created a webpage using HTML and JavaScript. My code is as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickyClick() {
          url = 'file:///mnt/sdcard/documents/instructies/' + document.getElementById("barcode").value + '.pdf'
            window.open(url, '_blank');
          document.getElementById("barcode").value = "";
        }
</script> <title>Open werkinstructie</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form><span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:50px;">Barcode:</span>
      <input autofocus="autofocus" style="font-size:50px" name="barcode" id="barcode"

        onkeydown="if (event.which == 13) clickyClick()" type="text"> </form>
    <br>
    <button style="height: 85px; width: 120px; font-size: 30px; font-weight:bold;"

      onclick="clickyClick()">Open</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which I open with Firefox on the tablet. For now I can't get it to work using the Barcode scanner or the enter key, the button however does work. This code opens the file in Adobe Reader, which is exactly what I want to do.

**UPDATE 2:**
*MainActivity.java:*

```
package com.example...............;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String TAG = null;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Klaar", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
        EditText.OnEditorActionListener exampleListener = new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                          KeyEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction, key=" + event.getKeyCode() + " action=" + event.getAction());
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    openPDF(mEditText.toString());
                    mEditText.setText("");
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void openPDF(String fileName){
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(baseDir + File.separator + "documents/instructies/"+fileName+".pdf");

        if (file.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No reader",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3:**
*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.example..............;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Klaar", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
        mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onEditorAction, key=" + event.getKeyCode() + "action =" + event.getAction());
                if (event.getAction() ==1 && event.getKeyCode() ==66) {
                    String Text = mEditText.getText().toString();
                    openPDF(Text);
                    mEditText.setText("");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void openPDF(String fileName) {
        File file = new File("sdcard/documents/instructies/" + fileName + ".pdf");
        //File file = new File("sdcard/documents/instructies/0195476.pdf");
        //final String LOG_TAG_2 = "MainActivity";
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG_2, "exist = " + file.exists());
        if (file.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No reader",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout add an EditText as this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

In your activity add this in onCreate method:

```
final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Done", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
EditText.OnEditorActionListener exampleListener = new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
            KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction, key="+event.getKeyCode() + " action="+event.getAction());
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            openPDF(mEditText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

To open a PDF, install a PDF app from market and in your activity open PDF as this:

```
private void openPDF(String fileName){

    File file = new File("/sdcard/pdf/"+fileName+".pdf");

    if (file.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No reader",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, we're using a real barcode scanner plugged in to the micro-usb port, so there's no need for an alternative barcode scanner. Furthermore, I have no experience in creating apps, so don't really know what to do with your code, I'm sorry

Comment: I've updated my original post with my progress. Perhaps you can help me with that, or guide me through the making of an app (I do have finished the hello world tutorial)

Comment: Barcode scanner is recognized by android as a keyboard or not ? What's model ? Do you have a SDK with it ?

Comment: I do not have a SDK with it, the barcode scanner is recognized as a keyboard. When I scan a barcode which represents the text: `test` the barcode scanner gives `test` + `enter` as output.

Comment: Thanks for your update, unfortunately I can't get it to work. I have copied your code in my project, but get an error message on `mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Done", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);`. I receive the message that `setImeActionLabel` cannot be resolved. I have imported the `Android.widget.EditText class`. When I comment out the line on which the error occures, the test app crashes.

Comment: What's "minSdkVersion" in AndroidManifest ?

Comment: Not specified, but I have selected 4.0.3 Icecream Sandwich on the creation of the project.

Comment: Please set minSDKVersion method "setImeActionLabel" is present since API 3

Comment: Sadly, no luck. I have added the line `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />` without succes. I recieve the same errors.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this? I'm getting a little lost.

Comment: Sorry, I'm such an idiot.. Just read the part where I need to add code to the onCreate method. Now the app works just fine, only one problem.. That is I can't execute any method. There is no `Go` button on the virtual keyboard, and the `Enter` that the barcode scanner gives just gives me a new line.

Comment: Just set the `android:SingeLine` attribute of the edittext to True, which stops the newline, but the code doesn't execute yet.

Comment: Do I have to do something with the `TAG`? Because when I add this line to my code, I receive the error: `'TAG' has private access in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'`

Comment: @Wouter, create a local String property or replace directly TAG by a string as you want

Comment: I added the line `final String TAG = null;` (because the debugger wouldn't let me add a variable unless I made it final). But I don't think this is right, the app is still not working. I'm so sorry, I'm probably doing something stupid. I'll update my post with my current code.

Comment: @Wouter It's Android basic, please see http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: I'm sorry, as mentioned before, not an android developer, but I'm trying. I'll check your link.

Comment: Sorry to keep coming back, I have checked the logging and now I can catch the `enter` action. But whenever I press `enter` the application crashes (on real devices/ not in the emulator) can you please help me figure this out? I've updated my OP.

Comment: Finally I have it working, took me some time to learn how to debug in Android Java, but the app is finished, thanks for your effort!